# How to print right/center justified text from an index in C/C++?

Tags: c, char-pointer

I'm pretty bad at using `char*`'s in C/C++ and am asking for such an effect:

Say I have a text editor or viewer and I want to show line numbers on the side. My implementation would be the following (please point out any faults in this if possible):

```cpp
unsigned int line_number_width = 5;
char* lines = strdup(buffer->text);
char* line = strtok(lines, "\n");
unsigned line_number = 1;
while (line != NULL && line_number<= buffer->height) {
    printf("???:%.*s\n", !!line_number, line_number_width!!, buffer->width - line_number_width - 1, line);
    line = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    line_number++;
}
free(lines);
```

I want the following to print out:

```
  1:line1
  2:line2
  3:line3
  4:line4
  5:line5
  6:line6
  7:line7
  8:line8
  9:line9
 10:line10
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
100:line100
```

Notice how the `:`'s are all aligned in the same column.

What should I replace `???` with so that I get the following effect where the number passed is enclosed in a rectangle of length line_number_width, which are the arguments between `!!..!!`, such that the passed number is justified right in that imaginary rectangle?

Comment: No such language as C/C++, it's clear that you are really programming in C.

Comment: Doesn't `%*d` work for you?

Comment: Read [*how to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [more](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) about  [C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

Answer (score -1):

OK, I think I got an answer:

```cpp
unsigned int line_number_width = 5;
char* lines = strdup(buffer->text);
char* line = strtok(lines, "\n");
unsigned line_number = 1;
while (line != NULL && line_number<= buffer->height) {
    printf("%*d%.*s\n", line_number_width-(unsigned int)(log10(line_number)), line_number, buffer->width - line_number_width, line);

    line = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    line_number++;
}
free(lines);
```

Comment: Wrong place to write that. Use https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes, I'm really sorry, I have edited it to reach my final answer based on the suggested thread.